# why dont i get all multiples of ten when using this line of code?

Tags: pygame

Can anyone tell me why im not printing all multiples of ten, it seems to skip over chunks at random?

```py
if pygame.time.get_ticks()%10 == 0:
        print (pygame.time.get_ticks())
```

Comment: Assuming you just have this in a loop, the problem is it's not getting *called* every millisecond. So you're only seeing a time when the loop starts on a 0 tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) it says 'Return the number of milliseconds since pygame.init() was called.'

You check if the elapse msec returned by get_ticks ends in a 0 and if so you print.

Your game logic is not likely to take less than a msec so each time you make this call you will get back some number the last digit of which will move around but statistically has a 1/10 chance of ending in a 0 and causing you to print. Even if you make this call in less than 10 msec intervals, say every 3 msec as an example, you would only get e return that ended in 0 every 30 msec. Your calls are going to be more erratically timed than that, but statistically it will likely end up about 1/10 calls end in a 0. So there will be significant chunks of time between prints even if it called reasonably frequently.

By the way you should not call get_ticks() twice, but should call it once and save it in a temp variable which you test and print instead, but that is besides the point.